# GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes always returns an empty collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a generic editor `div` I'm putting together. Some of the fields are required and I'd like to add unobtrusive validation. There is a view model associated with these fields but it's stored in a collection and this `div` is independent of that collection.

So my model looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<GridModel> GridModels { get; set;}
}

public class GridModel
{
    [Required]
    public string GridField { get; set; }
}
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<div class="EditorDiv">
    @Html.TextBox("GridField")
</div>
```

Based on my research I should be able to do something like this:

```
@{
    var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(GridModel));
}
@Html.TextBox("myGridField", Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("GridField", metadata))
```

This compiles and runs just fine but `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` always returns an empty collection. What am I missing?

Comment: I had a similar problem and I found out that first time you call GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes it stores in the viewcontext that it has been processed. when you call it a second time, it notices and returns empty results. Considering this may help someone else with such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the model in your view is `@model GridModel`, (and assuming its inside a `<form>` tag), then using `@Html.TextBox("GridField")` will generate the correct `data-val-*` attributes.

The actual output of your html is

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The GridField field is required." id="GridField" name="GridField" type="text" value="">
```

However if the model in the view is `MyViewModel` then using `@Html.TextBox("GridField")` means you attempting to bind to a property of `MyViewModel` which does not exist and therefore the output would be

```
<input id="GridField" name="GridField" type="text" value="">
```

In order to bind to your model properties, you would need a `for` loop (or `EditorTemplate` for type of `GridModel`)

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.GridModels.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GridModels[i].GridField)
    }
}
```

which will generate (for the first `GridModel` in the collection)

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The GridField field is required." id="GridModels[0].GridField" name="GridModels[0].GridField" type="text" value="">
```

Side note: The issue with you last snippet of code is that you getting the validation attributes for the class (which do not exist), not the property and it would need to be

```
@{
    var typeMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(GridModel));
    var propertyData = typeMetadata.Properties.Where(x => x.PropertyName == "GridField").FirstOrDefault();
```

and the results of `propertyData` would be an Dictionary containing 2 items

```
{[data-val-required, The GridField field is required.]}
{[data-val, true]}
```

Not that you would ever need that code in a view, but if you did, using `@Html.TextBox("myGridField", propertyData)` would not work anyway since its using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29), and you would need [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a my helpers.

if i have a ModelName = `GridModels[0].GridField`
and i call a method:

```
htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ModelName)
```

it return `empty dictionary`.

Because i'm in a helper, if i call a method with `ModelMetadata` (loaded by expression) parameter, it work:

```
var ModelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData)
htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ModelName, ModelMetadata )
```

and finally return the correct dictionary :)

Comment: In my case, I accidentally called this helper twice to render Html string for the same property which somehow caused the validation attributes to always be empty.

Comment: @jom If you would call many time the method, you need to call this code:

`string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToString();
htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.RenderedField(fullHtmlFieldName, false);`

Comment: @DavideCiarmiello This doesn't work in this case when the property path includes an index because `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` seems to remove the `[x]` from the `fullHtmlFieldName` when it stores it. E.G. If I called GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes for `Model.GridModels[0].GridField` `FormContext._renderedFields` will contain `{ "Model.GridField", True }`. So it uses the same name regardless of the index. Any idea why or how to solve?